# C# interop with Word wildcards: how to include optional space in Find?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

It's pretty simple to include an optional space in a regex search (e.g., \s?) but I'm learning the MS Word's Selection.Find only supports a subset of regex. It has support for including 1 or more specific characters, including spaces, but doesn't support zero occurrences?

I'm trying to find text that matches

```
1BEGIN
```

or

```
1 BEGIN
```

As mentioned, this isn't supported by Word:

```
Find.Text = @"1\s?BEGIN";
```

This works for one or more spaces, so finds "1 BEGIN"

```
Find.Text = @"1 {1,}BEGIN";
```

But this throws an exception when I try it for zero occurrences:

```
Find.Text = @"1 {0,}BEGIN";
```

Of course this works:

```
Find.Text = @"1*BEGIN";
```

But it also finds "123BEGIN", which isn't what I want. Is there a Word-friendly search for an optional space?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You'd need to run two separate "Find" sequences.

Comment: Or one Find sequence on either the term before or the term following the space then have your code check what is on the other side of the space.